# ACTION_SEND: Incorrect mime sent to WhatsApp resulting in missing Thumbnails

Tags: android, android-intent, android-support-library, android-sharing

My App manages a few videos and photos downloaded from a IoT device. It downloads videos & photos from these devices and places them in the Apps external `Downloads` directory (retrieved with `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)`).

The App offers a **sharing** feature, which utilizes the `ACTION_SEND` intent to export a file to another application.

I have observed different behavior with my App, based on the phones Android OS version. My test is simple: Share the same file (a single photo) to 3 different Apps: 1) WhatsApp, 2) Gmail 3) [InShot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.camerasideas.instashot&hl=en).

#### On Android 7.0, the App behavior is incomplete:

1. WhatsApp: Can not show image thumbnail, the file is sent as a "document".
   [image: WhatsApp demonstration screenshot]
2. Gmail: No problems, the file is sent passed over to Gmail correctly, including a thumbnail
   [image: Gmail demonstration]
3. InShot: Can not retrieve the file and shows a error message.
   [image: InShot demontration]

#### On Android 8.0, everything works as expected.

1. WhatsApp: Shows the video or photo editor, then copies the file correctly.
2. Gmail: No problem, as above.
3. InShot: No problem, file can be imported.

### Code

The App is using a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to export the files as it's the standard on Android now.

Support library version is **27.1.0**.

The relevant code parts looks like this:

#### AndroidManifest.xml

Nothing special, just the default config and a link to the paths.xml. applicationId and filesAuthority placeholders are correctly replaced.

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}${filesAuthority}"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/paths"/>
</provider>
```

#### paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="Download"
        path="Download"/>
</paths>
```

#### `createSharingIntent(context: Context, videos: List<Video>): Intent`

```
var hasVideos = false
var hasImages = false

var items = emptyArray<ClipData.Item>()
var contentTypes = emptyArray<String>()

// Create ClipData items & contentTypes which help to further specify the Intent contents.
for (video in videos) {
    items += ClipData.Item(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.FILES_AUTHORITY, File(video.path)))
    contentTypes += (if (video.isJpg) IMAGE_JPG else MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC)

    if (video.isJpg) {
        hasImages = true
    } else {
        hasVideos = true
    }
}

// Build the Intent
val intent: Intent

val intentType = when {
    hasImages && hasVideos -> "*/*"
    hasImages -> IMAGE_JPG
    else -> MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC
}

intent = if (items.size > 1) {
    Intent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE)
            .setType(intentType)
            .putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, ArrayList(items.map { it.uri }))
} else {
    Intent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            .setDataAndTypeAndNormalize(items[0].uri, intentType)
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, items[0].uri)
}

intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION.or(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)

// Specify more detail in ClipData - which might be helpful for 
val clipData = ClipData("Export", contentTypes, items[0])
for (i in 1 until items.size) {
    clipData.addItem(items[i])
}
intent.clipData = clipData

return intent
```

#### take intent and send

```
Intent intent = createSharingIntent(activity, videos)
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, activity.getString(R.string.share_files));
activity.startActivity(chooser);
```

What is missing to create the same behavior - and most importantly - ensure WhatsApp and other apps can see the image properly, like Gmail?

Comment: Apparently, my though about the MIME was incorrect - the file extension needs to be in lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was resolved by ensuring the filename is passed along in lowercase.

Some Android phones did trip over this while others didn't.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the solution. I was going crazy over this :) Just wondering how did you came up with the solution?

Comment: @zeke mostly by pulling a lot of hair and testing on all the different Android phones in the office.